# How to sum diagonal values in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to find diagonal sum by using 5 column values. For w1, selected diagonal values sum is calculated and for w2, B3 onwards diagonal values has to be considered.How to acheive this in pyspark code.

[image]

Data can be copied as below:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  w| Col1| Col2| Col3| Col4| Col5|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| w1|161.8|161.8|161.8|161.8|161.8|
| w2|112.0|112.0|112.0|112.0|112.0|
| w3|157.7|157.7|157.7|157.7|157.7|
| w4|146.1|146.1|146.1|146.1|146.1|
| w5|193.4|193.4|193.4|193.4|193.4|
| w6| 44.7| 44.7| 44.7| 44.7| 44.7|
| w7|105.3|105.3|105.3|105.3|105.3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be fairly trivial in pandas using `shift` so if your data is small enough it might just be easier to write a UDF and pass the entire dataset to it.

In any case, you can use `lag` in pyspark.  You'll need to create a window function, which requires a grouping and ordering, which you really want to be a single group, and the order to be basically the same order the data is already in.  To solve this you can assign everything to group `1` and order by `monotonically_increasing_id`.

Then create lags of your columns, starting at 0 and decreasing one per column.  Then you can sum these up.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 5)), columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']))
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)



df = df.withColumn('group',F.lit(1))
df = df.withColumn('order', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window.partitionBy(F.col('group')).orderBy(F.col('order'))


df = df.withColumn('lag1',F.lag(F.col('col1'),0).over(w)) \
       .withColumn('lag2',F.lag(F.col('col2'),-1).over(w)) \
       .withColumn('lag3',F.lag(F.col('col3'),-2).over(w)) \
       .withColumn('lag4',F.lag(F.col('col4'),-3).over(w)) \
       .withColumn('lag5',F.lag(F.col('col5'),-4).over(w))


display(df.withColumn('diagonal_sum',reduce(add, [F.col(x) for x in df.columns if 'lag' in x])))
```

Output

```
        col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    group         order  lag1   lag2    lag3    lag4    lag5    diagonal_sum
0         94      44      91      91      39        1   25769803776    94   96.0    19.0    56.0    28.0    293.0
1         77      96       0      25      70        1   51539607552    77   94.0    76.0    7.0 NaN NaN
2         87      94      19      76      63        1   77309411328    87   26.0    67.0    NaN NaN NaN
3         68      26      76      56      34        1   103079215104   68   32.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN
4         78      32      67       7      28        1   128849018880   78   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69165429/9840637) , you can use reduce with lead after coalescing the nulls as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
from functools import reduce
w = W.orderBy(order_col)

order_col = 'w'
othercols = df.columns[1:]    
out = df.withColumn("DiagSum",reduce(lambda x,y: F.round(x+y,2),
[F.coalesce(F.lead(F.col(col),e).over(w),F.lit(0)) for e,col in enumerate(othercols)]))
```

---

```
out.show()

+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|  w| Col1| Col2| Col3| Col4| Col5|DiagSum|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| w1|161.8|161.8|161.8|161.8|161.8|  771.0|
| w2|112.0|112.0|112.0|112.0|112.0|  653.9|
| w3|157.7|157.7|157.7|157.7|157.7|  647.2|
| w4|146.1|146.1|146.1|146.1|146.1|  489.5|
| w5|193.4|193.4|193.4|193.4|193.4|  343.4|
| w6| 44.7| 44.7| 44.7| 44.7| 44.7|  150.0|
| w7|105.3|105.3|105.3|105.3|105.3|  105.3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```